# What am I doing wrong in attempting to find the least squares solution of the system Ax = b?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am attempting to find the least-squares solution x* of the system Ax = b, where 
$$
        A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
        B = \begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm trying to solve for x* using the formula $$x^* = (A^TA)^{-1} A^Tb $$
I am getting stuck after I calculate  $$(A^TA)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        66 & 78 & 90 \\
        78 & 93 & 108 \\
        90 & 108 & 126 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
because I am getting an error when I attempt to calculate the inverse of this matrix in my calculator. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A^TA$ is not full rank because the matrix $A$ is not full rank. This is why you cannot invert it.
Re-express the system using only linearly independent rows. The matrix $A$ is of rank 2.  Re-express your system with a $2\times 3$ matrix.  With this representation, you can use the least square formula.

Comment: Agh, I get it now! I need to ignore two of the columns in A and then plug that 3x1 matrix into the formula. I've run some regressions in Stata before, but I only just realized why a regression that includes duplicate variables omits duplicate occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of $A$ is $0$, hence it is not invertible.

Comment: So then does that mean it is impossible to calculate a least-squares solution?